# How to return second newest record in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

If this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Date=( SELECT MAX(Date)
             FROM Table
           )
```

returns newest record from the table, how to get **second newest** record?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE Date = ( SELECT MAX(Date) 
               FROM Table
               WHERE Date < ( SELECT MAX(Date) 
                              FROM Table
                            )
             ) ;
```

or:

```
SELECT TOP (1) * 
FROM Table
WHERE Date < ( SELECT MAX(Date) 
               FROM Table
             ) 
ORDER BY Date DESC ;
```

or:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT t.*
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM Table t
  ) AS tmp
WHERE RowNumber = 2 ;
```

---

If the `Date` column has unique values, all three queries will give the same result. If the column can have duplicate dates, then they may give different results (when there are ties in 1st or 2nd place). The first query will even give multiple rows in the result if there are ties in 2nd place.

Comment: They are all returning two records if the dates are the same, any solution for this?

Comment: The 2nd and 3rd query will always return 1 record or none.

Comment: So, it depends on how you want to deal with ties. What do you want returned when all rows have identical dates?

Answer (score 8):

```
"select TOP (1) * 
 from Table   
 WHERE Date<(SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Table) 
 ORDER BY Date DESC"
```

should do the trick.

Comment: order by date descending and it will :D  except limit isn't in SQL 2008...  but top is.

Comment: The `LIMIT` clause isn't supported in SQL Server. Use `TOP` instead. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Please check this code.

```
SELECT * FROM category 
WHERE Created_Time <(
                     SELECT MAX(Created_Time) 
                     FROM category
                     ) 
ORDER BY Created_Time DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Prasad.

Comment: Oh Sorry. My fault. I didn't see which SQL server is. Thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 1):

select second last date in sql:

```
 SELECT MAX(YourDateColumn) FROM YourTable where ColumnId=2 and  YourDateColumn <
(SELECT MAX(YourDateColumn) FROM YourTable where ColumnId=2)
```

hope helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table
WHERE Date = ( SELECT MAX(Date)  FROM Table
             WHERE Date < ( SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Table)
         ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If using SQL Server 2012 or newer, OFFSET / FETCH is now available to support doing this task more directly:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table t
ORDER BY t.[Date] DESC
OFFSET 1 ROW
FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

And a general warning about this task; in the event that your data may have two more records that have the same date value, this code will behave non-deterministically. That is, it could return one row the first time you run it, and another row the next time.

To avoid this, you can add more sorting criteria to guarantee a deterministic sorting. Simplest way to guarantee this is to also sort by the primary key of the table. As follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table t
ORDER BY
    t.[Date] DESC
    ,t.ID DESC
OFFSET 1 ROW
FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```