# Get second highest date from related table

Tags: mysql, laravel, date, eloquent

I am trying to fetch the second highest date from a relation-table in with Eloquent Laravel 6.

```
MoodTable
id    animal_id  date          mood
1     1          2019-12-14    happy
2     1          2019-12-11    drunk
3     1          2019-12-13    sad

AnimalTable
id    name
1     Dog
```

So for example, I want to be able to query: "Today Dog is happy. Prevously to that he was Drunk.

To fetch the highest I use:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\AnimalMood', 'animal_id')->select(DB::raw('
                    mood,
                    animal_id,
                    MAX(date) as max_date,  
                    '))
                 ->groupBy('stock_id');
```

However, when it comes to seconed highest date... I'm out...

I have looked at [How to return second newest record in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590296/how-to-return-second-newest-record-in-sql)
for some answers,but not been able to put that in a relationship senario nor translate it to Eloquent.

Ideally, I would like to run `Animal::with('moodPrevious')->get()` and `Animal::find(1)->moodPrevious` from my controller...

Comment: You could do a count on a sub-query that counts the dates that are higher than the current one. If the count is 1, you have the second highest.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the relationship and grab all of the related models to your `Animal` model when you query for it.

`return $this->hasMany('App\AnimalMood', 'animal_id');`

Below returns the animals with the moods pre-sorted.

```
$animals = Animal::with(['mood' => function($q){
               $q->orderByDesc('date');
           }])->get();
```

Laravel offers a lot of collection methods that work well with related models. I would use the callback you can provide to `first()` in order to get the mood you want on the model. You probably already have the specific model you want, either by foreaching over the above collection or something similar. The relation will be a `collection` instance so we use the collection method to get the `mood` desired.

```
$previousMood = $animal->mood->first(function($value, $key){
    return $key == 1 // You can use whatever here, this will return the second item on the relation, or the previous mood.
});
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-first for a reference.

Comment: It will work, thank you. However the Animal table has about 300 rows and the Mood table is updated daily. Meaning for the duration of one year I would put 109500 rows in the query... This would depand quite a lot of performance, no?

Comment: It depends. If you need a full report for a whole year that may take some time, but that's going to happen no matter how you slice it. You can constrain the initial query to reduce the total number returned if performance becomes an issue down the line.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work

```php
return $this->hasMany('App\AnimalMood', 'animal_id')
    ->select(
        DB::raw('
            mood,
            animal_id,
            MAX(date) as max_date,  
        ')
    )
    ->where(
        DB::raw("
            date = (
                SELECT 
                    MAX(date) 
                FROM animal_moods 
                WHERE date < (
                    SELECT 
                        MAX(date) 
                    FROM 
                    animal_moods
                )
            )
        ")
    )
    ->groupBy('stock_id');
```

Comment: This isn't a scalable solution.