# How to get 2nd highest salary from db

Tags: mysql

To find highest salary from db we use max in query.

How to get 2nd highest salary from db. can any one suggest the sq query

Comment: did you try to google it? there are plenty of results for [sql select second highest value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100/what-is-the-simplest-sql-query-to-find-the-second-largest-value)

Comment: Whats your data structure? Tables? Sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
SELECT max(salary) 
FROM mytable
WHERE salary < (
   SELECT max(salary) FROM mytable
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Far to many ways to achieve this.

```
SELECT Salary 
FROM Salarytable 
ORDER BY Salary DESC
LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: I guess, you are ordering not by the right field. It will probably work only, if  lower SalaryID means higher salary.

Comment: @Jacobian Whoops, My bad was meant to just say salary!