# How do I get the second max using SQL?

Tags: sql, max

I had that question in a code interview, I found a possible solution but I want to hear from you so thanks for your comments and help.

```
Select max(ID) from table where ID not in (select max(ID) from table)
```

Comment: @melpomene thanks I fixed it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100/what-is-the-simplest-sql-query-to-find-the-second-largest-value

Comment: @MitchWheat I've found the solution on google after my test and it was similar to mine but I don't see any problem hearing from experts like you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a window function:

```
select *
from (
   select x.*, 
          row_number() over (order by x.id) as rn
   from the_table x
) t
where rn = 2;
```

Comment: Very interesting thanks!