# SQL Query: DELETE all rows except for the xx most-recent

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I'm writing a script to check RSS feeds on regular intervals and need to prune out old articles.  I came across this answer which seems really close to what I'm looking for: [SQL query: Delete all records from the table except latest N?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578867/sql-query-delete-all-records-from-the-table-except-latest-n)

I need a similar solution that works the same way, except it keeps N articles per feed (and not N articles in general).  Each article has a field named "RSSFeedID" which references a specific feed in another table.  So for each RSSFeedID, I need to keep only N articles.

Any idea on how to do this?  Either the raw SQL query or LINQ-to-SQL code would be very helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: if only we had your object model ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your two tables are called RSSFeeds, RSSPosts, here is how you could do it. **Pseudocode** provided.

```
idList = query("SELECT unique id FROM RSSFeeds");
for each id in idList
    query("
    DELETE FROM RSSPosts 
    WHERE id NOT IN 
        (SELECT id 
         FROM RSSPosts 
         WHERE RSSFeedId = @id
         ORDER BY id DESC 
         LIMIT 10)
    ");
end
```

Comment: Perfect! I knew it would involve a subquery, I just couldn't wrap my head around it.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is overkill. Why not do this on per feed basis when you add a new article to a specific feed, using the same approach?