# Posts and tags - limit in join

Tags: mysql, select, join, limit

I have 3 tables: *posts*, *tags*, *posts_tags* . I want to list posts, and all tags associated with them, but to limit the results.

This is what I do now:

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    t.*
FROM 
    (
        SELECT * FROM  posts LIMIT 0, 10
    ) as p
    LEFT JOIN
        posts_tags as pt
        ON pt.post_id = p.post_id
    LEFT JOIN
        tags as t
        ON t.tag_id = pt.tag_id
```

It is working fine, but it seems to be a little bit slow..

Is there a better/faster way of doing this? Can I apply LIMIT somewhere else for better results?

**EDIT:** I want to limit posts, and not results. A post can have many tags.

Comment: Did you set correct indexes? posts_tags.post_id, posts.post_id, tags.tag_i and posts_tags.tag_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried moving the limiting subquery to the where clause instead:

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    t.*
FROM 
    posts as p
LEFT JOIN
    posts_tags as pt
    ON pt.post_id = p.post_id
LEFT JOIN
    tags as t
    ON t.tag_id = pt.tag_id
WHERE
    p.post_id in (select post_id from post limit 0,10)
```

Comment: Combining your answer with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124418/mysql-subquery-limit
I got the solution. This is much faster than my initial query. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    p.*,
    t.*
FROM 
    posts as p
    LEFT JOIN
        posts_tags as pt
        ON pt.post_id = p.post_id
    LEFT JOIN
        tags as t
        ON t.tag_id = pt.tag_id
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Should work ;)

**EDIT**

MySQL is quite slow when running multiple joins, in my opinion it's better to separate your query into two and then join the result in your app code (application overhead should not be so big since its only 10 results).

Comment: Yes it works but I want to limit the number of posts not the number of results. I post can have many tags..

Comment: @TamasPap please add this info into your question

Comment: I think that having tables: posts, tags, posts_tags makes it clear that I have a many to many relationship.

Comment: @TamasPap you said `... with them, but to limit the results.` so you got the answer how to do this ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try running your query with the EXPLAIN keyword in front of it:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```

This will give you and idea about how MySQL is executing your query. Maybe you miss a key or an index somewhere. Here's how to read the result of EXPLAIN:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I refreshed my knowledge about EXLPAIN SELECT :)