# Group by only for "limit and offset" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Whilst trying to do pagination I've run into this problem.
My table-

```
ID   CarBrand    Car Model
---------------------------
1    Alfa Romeo  Guilietta
2    Alfa Romeo  Mito

3    Audi        A3
4    Audi        R8
5    Audi        TT

6    Fiat        Punto
7    Fiat        Panda

8    Ford        Mondeo
9    Ford        Mustang

10   Nissan      Almera
11   Nissan      Note
12   Nissan      Qashqai

13   Toyota      Aygo
14   Toyota      Prius

15   Volkswagen  Beetle
16   Volkswagen  Golf
17   Volkswagen  Polo
18   Volkswagen  Up
```

I have the data displayed like so, in groups of two:

```
-Fiat  - Punto
         Panda

-Ford  - Mondeo
         Mustang
```

So there are 2 brands but 4 database results.
Is it possible to have a query limit and offset my results to two brands while showing all the models for the brand?

Sorry if I'm not clear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear. Try this:

```
select * from t t1
join (
  select distinct carBrand from t
  limit 2
) s on t1.carBrand = s.carBrand
```

Before the `limit 2` apply the ordering you want.

Comment: Perfectly logical, but I'm using MySQL and getting this problem: #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: This is a derived table and there is no `in/all/any/some`. This would happen to Alp's solution not mine :) [Working example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4721f/2) Anyway, what version are you using?

Comment: Thanks ^.^ it's just a tricky workaround to those yet-unimplemented features in MySQL

Comment: Well it clearly works! I'm not an expert on versions but my Xampp says mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev if that is right? Anyway after some more prodding I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124418/mysql-subquery-limit which after some fiddling I ended up with something similar to this for my actual tables: SELECT *
FROM t
JOIN t AS aa
ON t.carBrand = aa.carBrand
WHERE t.carBrand = ANY
(
   SELECT * FROM
   (
      SELECT bb.carBrand
      FROM t AS bb
      GROUP BY carBrand
      LIMIT 2
      OFFSET 3
 )
  AS cc
)

Comment: so it seems you're not allowed a limit in a subquery but are allowed a limit in a subquery subquery with my version?
Thank you for your solution though, I'm sure it will come in handy :)

Comment: My query needs GROUP BY aa.carModel at the end of it. And by the way,  on sqlfiddle it only returns the first columns, I had to specify "SELECT aa.carbrand, aa.carmodel" at the start too or I got the wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

To get a limit, without using the `limit` keyword, you can impose a count.

For example, given the table definition

```
create table cars (id int,
                   carBrand char(10),
                   carModel char(10));
```

this will give you all the Car Models for the top 2 Car Brands

```
select cars.carBrand, cars.carModel
from cars
where  ((select count(*) from 
           (select distinct carBrand from cars) as carBrands
        where carBrands.carBrand < cars.carBrand) < 2)
order by cars.carBrand, cars.carModel;
```

This creates an inline table just listing the `carBrands` and then joins this back to cars to get the list of all cars that are in the top 2 brands.  The `count(*) .... < 2` enforces the limit.  Consider `'Ford'`, for example, in your above data.  In '`Ford'`'s  case, there are 3 brands that are `< 'Ford'` alphabetically, so the `count(*)` above = 3.  Since 3 is not less than 2, no `'Ford'` cars appear in the output.

The output on your test data would be:

```
CARBRAND    CARMODEL
Alfa Romeo  Guilietta
Alfa Romeo  Mito
Audi        A3
Audi        R8
Audi        TT
```

Now, you didn't say how you wanted to pick the 2 brands -- you just listed Ford and Fiat in your example -- I don't know how you happened to pick those.  If you want something other than alphabetical criteria for ordering, that's doable, but harder.

SQL Fiddle and results for all this:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33a8f/3

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of database design. Maybe you should split your data into two tables `model` (model names) and `brand` (brand names). Then you can write a query like this:

```
SELECT m.name, b.name
FROM model m
INNER JOIN brand b
WHERE b.id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM brand
    ORDER BY name ASC
    LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0
)
```

I did not test the code. No need for `GROUP BY` in my opinion.

Comment: Perfectly logical, but I'm using MySQL and getting this problem: #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: Ok, i might be wrong with my answer then. Try [Mosty Mostacho's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10080818/675065) instead.