# PHP MySQL GROUP_CONCAT Limit

Tags: php, mysql, limit, group-concat

I couldn't find wether this was possible so, is there any option to limit a `GROUP_CONCAT` in MySQL-function?

E.g.:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(ColName ORDER BY ColName DESC LIMIT 5)
```

I don't want to use a subquery since this will seriously slow down the performance. I can slice the array later in PHP, but I was wondering or MySQL had an option to achieve this in MySQL already.

Comment: *"I don't want to use a subquery"* - You have to do something slightly bonkers to apply `LIMIT` to a sub-query anyway : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124418/mysql-subquery-limit

Comment: @CD001, I'm aware of that thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, but you can do this:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(ColName ORDER BY ColName DESC), ',', 5)
```

You may want to pay attention to the group concat maximum length (see [group_concat_max_len](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len)), if the intermediate string might be larger than 1024 characters.  You can change the default.

Comment: you have missed one ')' after desc

Comment: @GordonLinoff, great solution, thanks. The 1024 will be large enough, since I will only return 5 integers.