# Rails destroy all but newest n records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How do I destroy all but the newest n records using Rails' ActiveRecord?

I can get the newest n records using order and limit but how do I destroy the inverse?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Either of these methods would do it:

```
# Fetch your latest N records
newest_n_records = Foo.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => n)

# Then do:
Foo.destroy_all(['id NOT IN (?)', newest_n_records.collect(&:id)])

# Or:
Foo.destroy_all('created_at < ?', newest_n_records.last.created_at)
```

Comment: In Rails 4.2.0 you must send correct message to AR object: `Foo.all.order('created_at DESC').limit(n)`

Comment: Note that this will work on an [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all) because it accepts `conditions`. It will NOT work on an ActiveRecord::CollectionProxy because the `destroy_all` method simply runs `@association.destroy_all` without arguments. (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/58772397e9b790e80bcd4d8e51937dc82ecb719e/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L504-L506) Trying to use arguments in `destroy_all` for a CollectionProxy will raise an `ArgumentError` exception.

Answer (score 20):

I have two methods of doing this, assuming n = 5:

```
Foo.order('id desc').offset(5).destroy_all
```

This sorts records with latest first, and destroys everything past the 5th records.  Or

```
Foo.destroy_all(['id <= ?', Foo.order('id desc').limit(1).offset(5).first.id])
```

This finds the 6th latest record id and deletes all records with id <= 6th latest record id.

Also, you might want to look at this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578867/sql-query-delete-all-records-from-the-table-except-latest-n).

Comment: Nice idea using `.offset`. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
Foo.destroy_all(['id NOT IN (?)', Foo.last(1000).collect(&:id)])
```

Answer (score 5):

`Person.destroy_all("last_login < '2004-04-04'")`

This will destroy all persons who meet the condition. So all you need is inverted conditions and `destroy_all`

Comment: Worked for me, and if you're not worried about your model callbacks running and associations, you can call `delete_all` instead of `destroy_all` to do this in a single SQL DELETE statement to save instantiating a model object for each record.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers use `find` or `last` require the creation of ActiveModel, which take extra computation time.

I think using `pluck` is better, since it only creates an Array of ids.

```
ids = Foo.limit(n).order('id DESC').pluck(:id)
Foo.where('id NOT IN (?)', ids).destroy_all
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Rails 5 / ActiveRecord::Relation]**

[destroy_all](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all) no longer takes parameters... Actually, the ActiveRecord::Relation never allowed parameters I don't think... Anyway, you should just put the condition before it, but use destroy_all *after* the query, like this:

```
Person.destroy_all("last_login < '2004-04-04'")
Person.destroy_all(status: "inactive")
Person.where(age: 0..18).destroy_all
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these work in Rails 6, but `delete_by` [does](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35304).

```
keep_ids = [2345, 345256, 34]
Component.delete_by('id NOT IN (?) AND status = "inactive"', keep_ids) }
```