# MySQL DELETE all but latest X records

Tags: mysql, sql-delete, records

I have a script that runs every hour on my php site. In that script I would like some kind of MySQL query to delete every record from a table but say the latest 50.

How would I do something like that?

```
// pseudo code: like this?
DELETE from chat WHERE id = max (ID - 50)
```

Comment: Can you add a timestamp field to your table?

Comment: If your ID column is an identity column with autoincrement of 1, you could do somthing like that:
`DELETE FROM chat
WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT TOP 50 ID FROM chat ORDER BY ID DESC)`

Comment: In this case use:
`DELETE FROM chat WHERE datecol NOT IN(SELECT TOP 50 datecol FROM chat ORDER BY datecol DESC)-- SQL Server`

`DELETE FROM chat WHERE datecol NOT IN(SELECT datecol FROM chat ORDER BY datecol DESC LIMIT 50) --MySQL`

Comment: @user1022585 - I think you should delete based on a time span (between x and x), rather than the number of records.  Is there some reason why it has to be the last 50, rather than a time period/span?

Comment: `#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT &amp; IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL query: Delete all records from the table except latest N?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578867/sql-query-delete-all-records-from-the-table-except-latest-n)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could try using NOT IN:

EDIT for **MySQL**:

```
DELETE FROM chat WHERE id NOT IN ( 
  SELECT id 
  FROM ( 
    SELECT id 
    FROM chat 
    ORDER BY id DESC 
    LIMIT 50
  ) x 
);
```

This is for **SQL-Server**:

```
DELETE FROM chat WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT TOP 50 id FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC)
```

Assuming higher values of `id` are always newer.

Comment: Better order those IDs in DESCending order.

Comment: Tried this it doesnt work :/ I have a `date` field too if that helps

Comment: Whoops. Your question is tagged with SQL - try now using the MySQL solution.

Comment: `#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT &amp; IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Comment: It is now edited to avoid the subquery LIMIT problem - try now, it works.

Comment: The 2nd query is not for SQL in general. It only works in SQL-Server (and Ms-Access).

Comment: This works but I don't understand why I need the 'x' there. Anyone care to explain?

Comment: @user1767586 this comment is old but since I had the same question, here seems a good place to share the explanation I found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45498/3872061

Comment: You are the master! :)

Answer (score 2):

NOT IN is inefficient. You can slightly modify the first option in the previous answer by @Mithrandir to make it look like this:

```
DELETE from chat WHERE id < 
  (SELECT id FROM 
    (SELECT id FROM chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50) t ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
DELETE from chat WHERE id < (SELECT max(ID)-50 FROM chat)
```

This would work if your values for ID are incremented in steps of 1. Or you can use something like:

```
DELETE FROM chat WHERE id NOT IN 
    (SELECT id FROM ( SELECT ID FROM chat ORDER BY datetime_col DESC LIMIT 50) t ) -- mysql
```

Comment: What database system do you use?