# Deleting multiple rows in SQL/codeigniter

Tags: sql, codeigniter

This doesnt seem to work:

```
 /// delete emails first
         $this->db->where('DateSent', 'DateSent!=NULL');
        $this->db->delete('Emails');
```

I guess I need to use a loop. Not sure how to go about doing this. Can anyone help?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to look in the very useful [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#select) userguide you'll see the operator should be included as part of the first parameter not second. This should solve it:

```
$this->db->where('DateSent !=', 'NULL');
$this->db->delete('Emails');
```

Comment: Didn't work: A Database Error Occurred
Error Number:

Incorrect syntax near '='.

DELETE FROM Emails WHERE DateSent !=

Comment: Sorry had a typo... I've updated it to include single quotes around the NULL

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$this->db->query('
    DELETE FROM `Emails`
    WHERE id NOT IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM (
            SELECT id
            FROM `Emails`
            WHERE `Emails`.`DateSent` = NULL
        ) foo
    );
);
```

Query taken from [SQL query: Delete all records from the table except latest N?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578867/sql-query-delete-all-records-from-the-table-except-latest-n) then modified

Answer (score 0):

First you need to store the selected values into an array say "$checked"

```
$checked = implode(',',$checked);     //then it looks array('id1','id2','id3',..);
```

then you can delete as

```
$this->db->where("iUserId in",$checked);

$this->db->delete('my_table');
```

that's it.it works for me.i hope it useful for you.accept if its useful