# Deleting older database entries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to keep the 10 most recent entries in my database and delete the older ones. I tried `DELETE FROM people ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $excess`, but it just deleted the top 10 entries.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM people";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($count > 10) {
    $excess = $count - 10;
    $query = "DELETE FROM people WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM people ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT '$excess')";
    mysqli_query($conn, $query);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578867/sql-query-delete-all-records-from-the-table-except-latest-n

Comment: +1, subqueries for the win.

Comment: Do you really need to delete them?

Comment: A database runs fine even with a lot of `excess` data. If these entries are logs, you'll never have enough logs to slow down the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:-

```
DELETE FROM `people`
WHERE id NOT IN (
  SELECT id
  FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM `people`
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 10
  ) 
);
```

Also your query is logically incorrect and you are fetching the records in descending order. i.e. `Latest to older` and you are deleting the most recent records. Use `ASC` instead.

Comment: I had to add an alias after the first ")" as suggested by the first comment's link, but it seems to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? Gets the ten latest ids in the subquery, then deletes all of the other ids.

```
DELETE FROM people WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM PEOPLE ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10)
```

Comment: I'm getting #1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' ver. 5.0.91

Comment: Oh, you're using an older version of MySQL, then. If you can't update, I'd suggest making two queries - one to find the tenth id, and then using that to delete all queries that have older ids.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is all over the place, [you should `ORDER BY ASC`, not `DESC`] and your query will take ages if there are [for example] 10,000 entries because you'll have an `IN` clause with 9,990 entries to compare all 10,000 to.

Select the 10 most recent, and delete where NOT in.

```
DELETE FROM people
  WHERE id NOT IN(
    SELECT id 
    FROM people
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 10
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe find the ID of the 10th element and then delete all rows which are older?