# How to delete a certain row from mysql table with same column values?

Tags: mysql, delete-row

I have a problem with my queries in MySQL. My table has 4 columns and it looks something like this:

```
id_users    id_product    quantity    date
 1              2              1       2013
 1              2              1       2013
 2              2              1       2013
 1              3              1       2013
```

`id_users` and `id_product` are foreign keys from different tables.

What I want is to delete just one row:

```
1     2     1    2013
```

Which appears twice, so I just want to delete it.

I've tried this query:

```
delete from orders where id_users = 1 and id_product = 2
```

But it will delete both of them (since they are duplicated). Any hints on solving this problem?

Answer (score 210):

Add a `limit` to the [delete](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) query

```
delete from orders 
where id_users = 1 and id_product = 2
limit 1
```

Comment: This only deletes one row. If there were 3 with this user and product id then 2 would remain.

Comment: Yes, OP say (s)he wants to delete 1 row. That is what my query does.

Comment: Yes, but I think this is not what he/she wants.

Comment: What OP really needs to do is to check first what rows are duplicated then delete the duplicates.

Comment: In case of more copies than two this works if `limit 1` is modified to
`limit (select count(*)-1 from orders where [appropriate filters to select all duplicates])`.

Answer (score 64):

All tables should have a primary key (consisting of a single or multiple columns), duplicate rows doesn't make sense in a relational database. You can limit the number of delete rows using `LIMIT` though:

```
DELETE FROM orders WHERE id_users = 1 AND id_product = 2 LIMIT 1
```

But that just solves your current issue, you should definitely work on the bigger issue by defining primary keys.

Comment: This is good to mention that the primary key should be unique in a relational databse.

Comment: @Paul This is exactly what I about to say. But don't forget unique  key doesn't necessary means primary key.

Answer (score 20):

You need to specify the number of rows which should be deleted. In your case (and I assume that you only want to keep one) this can be done like this:

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE id_users=1 AND id_product=2
LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*)-1 FROM your_table WHERE id_users=1 AND id_product=2)
```

Comment: Thank you Rob, but no... I just want to delete one single row, not to keep just one

Comment: This is not working for me in 5.5.40, it throws a syntax error. As mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/578926/1076075, it seems like we can't use a subquery to specify the value of a LIMIT clause. For anyone trying to do stuff this way, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/578867/1076075

Answer (score 8):

Best way to design table is add one temporary row as auto increment and keep as primary key. So we can avoid such above issues.

Comment: Or a permanent row. I know this is an old question, but I though I should say it. Id's are used for this kind of situation. If you are worried about space: A BIGINT is only 8 bytes!

Answer (score 5):

There are already answers for Deleting row by `LIMIT`. Ideally you should have primary key in your table. But if there is not.

I will give other ways:

1. By creating [Unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html)

I see id_users and id_product should be unique in your example.

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE orders ADD UNIQUE INDEX unique_columns_index (id_users, id_product)
```

These will delete duplicate rows with same data.

But if you still get an error, even if you use IGNORE clause, try this:

```
ALTER TABLE orders ENGINE MyISAM;
ALTER IGNORE TABLE orders ADD UNIQUE INDEX unique_columns_index (id_users, id_product)
ALTER TABLE orders ENGINE InnoDB;
```

2. By creating table again

If there are multiple rows who have duplicate values, then you can also recreate table

```
RENAME TABLE `orders` TO `orders2`;

CREATE TABLE `orders` 
SELECT * FROM `orders2` GROUP BY id_users, id_product;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add an id that auto-increment for each row, after that you can delet the row by its id.
so your table will have an unique id for each row and the id_user, id_product ecc...