# MySQL: delete table rows if string in cell is matched?

Tags: mysql, sql, delete-row

I have a table with a column `meta_key` … I want to delete all rows in my table where `meta_key` matches some string.

[image]

For instance I want to delete all 3 rows with "tel" in it - nut just the cell but the entire row. How can I do that with a mysql statement?

Comment: delete from table where meta_key = 'tel'

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to delete certain row from mysql table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378190/how-to-delete-certain-row-from-mysql-table)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The below query deletes the row with strings contains "tel" in it  :

```
   DELETE FROM my_table WHERE meta_key like '%tel%';
```

This is part of [Pattern matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html).

If you want the meta_key string to be equal to "tel" then you can try below:

```
   DELETE FROM my_table WHERE meta_key = 'tel'
```

This is a simple [Delete](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE meta_key = 'tel' //will delete exact match

DELETE FROM table WHERE meta_key = '%tel%'//will delete string contain tel
```

Answer (score 1):

```
delete from tablename where meta_key = 'tel'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE meta_key = "tel";
```

For the future, try and read the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM table
        WHERE meta_key= 'tel';
```

In addition you can use `limit` to specify the amount of rows to delete