# keep last 10 and delete all other rows - sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to execute this below query.

```
db.delete(TABLE_SESSIONS, selectQuery, null);
```

The Select Query should be those except last 10 entries.

How to achieve this?

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SESSIONS +" WHERE " +KEY_SESSION_ID+ " IN (SELECT "+KEY_SESSION_ID + " FROM "+TABLE_SESSIONS+" WHERE " +KEY_SESSION_ID+ " ORDER BY Col LIMIT 10)";
```

Can anyone improve my query? ( I'm not good with query )

Comment: What exactly you are getting if you pass this query?

Comment: Refer this [sql-query-delete-all-records-from-the-table-except-latest-n](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578867/sql-query-delete-all-records-from-the-table-except-latest-n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try following query.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SESSIONS +" WHERE " +KEY_SESSION_ID+ " IN (SELECT "+KEY_SESSION_ID + " FROM "+TABLE_SESSIONS+" WHERE " +KEY_SESSION_ID+ " ORDER BY Col DESC LIMIT 10)";
```

Answer (score 4):

[`SQLiteDatabase` `delete()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) takes in a `WHERE` expression and not a `SELECT` statement.

If your selection returns those rows you want to keep:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SESSIONS +" WHERE " +KEY_SESSION_ID+ " IN (SELECT "+KEY_SESSION_ID + " FROM "+TABLE_SESSIONS+" WHERE " +KEY_SESSION_ID+ " ORDER BY Col LIMIT 10)"
```

... you can use this in the delete using `NOT IN` like this:

```
db.delete(TABLE_SESSIONS,
    "ROWID NOT IN (SELECT ROWID FROM " + TABLE_SESSIONS + " ORDER BY Col LIMIT 10)",
    null);
```

The `ROWID` is an alias for the `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` of a table; the `WHERE` condition you had in your subselect is not necessary as any non-zero ID gets selected.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM  TABLE_SESSIONS WHERE YOUR_SORT_FIELD NOT IN (select TOP 10 YOUR_SORT_FIELD from TABLE_SESSIONS order by YOUR_SORT_FIELD DESC)`

`DESC` and `ASC` can be changed if you need last ten or latest 10

and `YOUR_SORT_FIELD` is the field that identifies the latest data