# How to select last row of mysql_query?

Tags: php, mysql

It is possible to select last row selected by `mysql_query` in php without iterating using `mysql_fetch_row` from first row till last?

If so, what should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [mysql_data_seek](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) function:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row_num = mysql_num_rows($result); 
if (mysql_data_seek($result, $row_num - 1)) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);    
  ...
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 4):

How about `ORDER`-ing the results in  reverse order and getting the first element? Will that work ? (If you are only interested in that row, you can also use `LIMIT 1`)

Comment: In fact I need to select (e.g.) 20-th row, but if there are less than 20 rows selected I need last row from selected. Now I use LIMIT to select 20 rows and than select last row iterating via mysql_fetch_array. And I would like to avoid iterating

Comment: So sort it in reverse order, LIMIT 20, and get the first row.

Comment: In case of many records selected this will return 20-th record from the end, but I need 20-th from the beginning

Comment: In that case, you are better off using `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568/how-to-select-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-database-table

Answer (score 0):

Or, more simply this:

```
$count=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM whatever"));
$query="SELECT * FROM whatever LIMIT ".($count-1).", 1";
print_r(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query)));
```