# How to put row on top in mysql query.

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have 100 records in my SQL table i want to sort them ASC by name but i need one record on top of all record nr 43.

Is there way i can pull this record 43 first and then everything else ASC order by name?

Trick is to do it in one query.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568/how-to-select-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-database-table

Answer (score 30):

No UNIONs or CASEs needed:

```
ORDER BY id = 43 DESC, name ASC
```

Comment: super, this was exactly what i was looking for and i can confirm it works!

Answer (score 6):

Use this:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN (record is 43) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) to create a query that selects the first record then appends the set of records that should appear beneath.

E.g:

```
select * from table where id = 43;
union
select * from table where id <> 43;
```

Comment: Union does not guarantee an order without an order by.

Answer (score 0):

This query should add a column called priority, which has the value 1 on the record with id 43 and 0 on all others. Then you sort by priority first.

```
SELECT mytable.*, IF(id = 43, 1, 0) AS priority FROM mytable ORDER BY priority DESC, name ASC
```