# How to put a row on top in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, select

is there a way to order codeigniter select query by a specific value?

I know that it can be done in mysql from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6873423/7657853) answer, but I'm wondering if there is a "codeigniter" way of doing it, here is what I've tried:

```
$this->db->select('...');
$this->db->from('table_one');
$this->db->join('table_two', 'table_one.some_id = table_two.id', 'inner');
$this->db->where('city',$city);
// this gives me error
$this->db->order_by("table_two.id=$id", "desc");   
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result_array();
```

This gives me the unknown column error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes this is possible, but you need quotes:

```
$this->db->order_by("table_two.id='$id'", "desc");
```

hint: you can always doublecheck your query like this:

```
echo $this->db->last_query();die;
```