# fetch second highest paid employee salary from each department

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to fetch second highest paid employee salary from each department using SQL. Example, I've 100 departments with more than 500 employees in each department. & all these data is in one table.

Table Columns:
EmpNo,  EmpFirstName,   EmpLastName,    DepartmentNo,   DepartmentName, Salary

Output:
EmpNo,  EmpFirstName,   EmpLastName,    DepartmentName, Salary

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752458/how-select-second-line-from-top-2-or-something-similar and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568/how-to-select-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-database-table

Comment: Sorry, Doesn't help...