# SQL Server, select a record every 'x' amount of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

[image]

Hi,

I have “Table1” as shown above with some records on it and the column names are Id, Name and [Entry Date]. Column Id is primary key, I am using SQL Server 2005.

I want to write a query that returns information every 5 records, for example my query will return:

[image]

As you can see in the final result only the record every 5 records was selected, how can I accomplish this?

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568/how-to-select-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-database-table and this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx.  The trick is to use SQL's ROW_NUMBER() OVER and the modulo command.

Comment: you cant do this with sql query UNLESS sql server provides a way to trigger a procedure every x amount of seconds, otherwise you will need to use some language, you will also have to keep track of the data you have fetched.

Comment: 1, 5, 10, 15.  That isn't every 5.  The first difference is 4, whereas all subsequent are 5.  Do you mean 1, 6, 11, 16, ....?

Comment: @Shark, thanks for input. The number of records to skip is not relevant at this point. I just wanted to be able to skip certain number of records every 'n' number, so it can be 4 or 5 or 6. But thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name, entryDate 
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) rowNumber, Id, name, entryDate
          FROM MyTable)
  WHERE rowNumber = 1
     OR rowNumber % 5 = 0
```

Comment: Heh!  You even cater for what is surely a mistake in the loigc on the OPs part, nice :)

Comment: Thank you Bassam, the solution you offerd works as intended.I accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from mytable 
where id = 1 or id % 5 = 0
```

Comment: This won't work if there are gaps between ids due to deletion

Comment: Assumes all records are sequential. No deletes. No failed inserts. Etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the IDs are sequential and unique (which they appear to be), just index += 5 for every record. Some pseudo code for this:

```
$index = 0;
while ( $index <= $totalRecords ) {
   $result = "select * from records where id='$index'";
   /*process results*/
   $index += 5; /*increment index for next query*/
}
```

Note that for record ID=1, will be a special case since your IDs start at 1, and not 0.

Hope this gives you an idea.