# SELECT specific rows on access database

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, ms-access

I don't really know how to ask it in the title, but I will try my best on explaining it here..
First, I tried to look at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568/how-to-select-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-database-table).. The thing is, I cannot follow its statement. It dances in my head.

Here's what I am aiming for.
 *get the following IDs of the next rows `WHERE fieldFoo = foo`*

Flow of the program (**MS Access & VB.Net**):
DGV's are not connected to the database, I just use them for Display of data that they will save/Update.

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM piglets WHERE CurrentLocation=@cl AND Week=@week AND SowOrder=@sow ORDER BY ID ASC"
```

1. User inserts a number, software checks if the data is there. If its there, it will add it to the DGV.
2. User needs to save the `UPDATE` query. **This works perfectly but only with ONE row.**
3. Since it gets only  one, it only gets an ID, which is what I basically user as their identity.

What I have tried:

1. I added a list of integer in which it will contain the ID each time a user looks up for a data, add it to the DGV, look again, add to DGV. But it only returns the same item, that's why when I try to save, it only updates that one item.
2. Re-run the sub, but its an error, can't figure out why.

Here is the code for looking up the data

```
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@cl", comboFrom.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@week", mtWeek.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@sow", mtSow.Text)
        End With
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If dr.HasRows() Then
            If dr.Read() Then
                Do
                    Dim loc As String
                    loc = dr("CurrentLocation").ToString()
                    // id = dr("ID")
                    tempIdList.Add(dr("ID"))
                    If loc = comboFrom.Text Then
                        isContinue = True
                    End If
                Loop While dr.Read
            End If
        Else
            isContinue = False
            MessageBox.Show("Piglet look up error.", "MR Livestock", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            clear()
        End If
    End Using
```

This is how I save

```
Dim query As String = "UPDATE Piglets SET Mortality=@mortality, CurrentLocation=@me" & _
        " WHERE ID=@id"
    // For Each i In tempIdList
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvMortality.Rows
        Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
            With cmd.Parameters
                .AddWithValue("@mortality", row.Cells("mortality").Value)
                .AddWithValue("@me", "Mortality")
                .AddWithValue("@id", tempIdList.Item(id))
            End With
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            id = id + 1 // I was hoping here to have the IDs, but I forgot that the query gets only one, so if the are two items, they are the same.
        End Using
    Next
    // Next
```

The result that I want is for the user to be able to add multiple entries to the DGV, then can save it all at once using the ID that (*maybe pre-saved in a list*) is from the database. For now, I can save only one, since it gets the TOP 1 only, even if I entered as many data as I want.

Comment: hmm.. it also dances my head - 
actually you also display the `id` in the DGV, right?
when you want to save the updates of the rows in the DGV, each row will just need to read the value of the `id` column`..

Comment: I forgot, DGVs are not connected. I just use them for display.