# 3rd highest salary in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I had been looking for the query to find the 3rd highest salary from the database (using Oracle database). I found the below query -

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT e.*, row_number() over (order by sal DESC) rn FROM emp e
  )
WHERE rn = 3;
```

I do not have oracle installed in my system, so I'm not try it out. But I want to know if the below query will work or not. If not, then why ?

```
WITH Sal_sort AS
  (SELECT DISTINCT sal FROM salary ORDER BY sal DESC
  )
SELECT * FROM Salary S, Sal_sort SS WHERE S.Sal = SS.Sal AND SS.rownum = 3;
```

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html download Express edition for testing.

Comment: You don't even have to install Oracle, you can also try this at http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: This is a variant of the "select the nth row" question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568/how-to-select-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-database-table.

Comment: "*I do not have oracle installed in my system*", go here: http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: the first highest is Larry Ellison

Answer (score 2):

**Input Data**

```
emp_no  emp_fname   emp_lname   salary
1   aa                      bb                      30  
2   ee                      yy                      31  
3   rr                      uu                      32  
4   tt                      ii                      33  
5   tt                      ii                      33  
6   tt                      ii                      33  
7   tt                      ii                      33  
8   tt                      ii                      30  
9   tt                      ii                      31
```

**Example:**

```
select * from ee;
select emp_no,salary ,dense_rank() over (order by salary  ) dr
from ee
```

**Output**

```
emp_no  salary  dr
1        30     1
8        30     1
9        31     2
2        31     2
3        32     3
4        33     4
5        33     4
6        33     4
7        33     4
```

Answer (score 0):

JUST ONE LINE

```
select * from (
select salary,dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) rank from  employees) where rank=3;
```

or

```
select * from (
select a.*,dense_rank() over (order by a.salary desc) rank from  employees a) where rank=3;
```

Answer (score 0):

So much easier in version 12 of the database and higher now.

```
SELECT *
  FROM employees
 ORDER BY salary DESC OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Tim talks about this feature [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1).

And if you take a look at the plan, you can see it's not magic, the optimizer is using analytic functions to derive the results.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Without Dense_rank()**

```
SELECT salary FROM employees
ORDER BY salary DESC
OFFSET 2
FETCH 1 NEXT ONE ROWS ONLY;
```

**With Dense_rank()**

```
SELECT salary 
FROM
(
SELECT salary, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) as rank from employees
)
WHERE rank = 3;
```