# How to create a dynamic procedure for threshold in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have 40+ tables, based on a certain columns limit, need to get a natural key (this is a natural key of a table which exceeded the threshold limit) and a column name, column value which exceeded the limit.

Example: table `f_revenue` has a column `rev_amt`. Natural key column are `revnbr` and `lastupdated`. If `rev_amt > 3000000` then 
insert the natural key (`revnbr, lastupdated`), `f_revenue`, `rev_amt`, rev_amt exceeded 3000000

How do you create a procedure in SQL Server to dynamically scroll through 40+ tables and do as the example above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop through all SQL tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496864/how-to-loop-through-all-sql-tables)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. (spring boarded from the comment above)

```
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(300)

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR
SELECT a.NAME 
FROM   SYS.TABLES a JOIN 
SYS.COLUMNS b ON a.object_id=b.object_id 
WHERE b.name IN ('nacturalkey', 'f_revenue', 'rev_amt') 

OPEN CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @NAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN 

      SET @SQL = 'SELECT nacturalkey, f_revenue, rev_amt FROM '+@Name+' WHERE rev_amt > 3000000' 

      PRINT @SQL
      EXEC Sp_executesql
        @SQL

      FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @NAME
  END

CLOSE CUR
```