# Iterate over multiple ga_sessions_[date] tables in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it possible to iterate over multiple ga_sessions tables in BigQuery?

I'm not asking about how to query multiple ga_sessions tables.
Which can be done in Standard SQL using: `select * from 'a:b.c.ga_sessions_*' where _TABLE_SUFFIX between '20180501' and '20180505'`.

I am asking about using a loop with date for example the answer in [While loop over tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496864/how-to-loop-through-all-sql-tables) uses variables and declare cursor.

The reason is because you can only query a limited number of tables using the [Querying Multiple Tables Using a Wildcard Table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables) method.

I suspect it is only possible using a programming language like Python, but wanted to check.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`
```

Or

```
SELECT * 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.*` 
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX IN (SELECT table_id 
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.__TABLES_SUMMARY__`
  WHERE table_id 
  LIKE 'ga_session_%')
```

To go through all the tables within the dataset. The limitations that may apply are for the [query job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs) ones (1000 tables referenced per query) and the current [wildcard table queries limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#limitations) which doesn't limit a number of tables.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason is because you can only query a limited number of tables
>   using the Querying Multiple Tables Using a Wildcard Table method.

What limit are you talking about? I do not see such a [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#limitations)

Anyway, you can `UNION` several query results with wildcards, e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `a:b.c.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '20180501' and '20180531' # MAY
UNION ALL 
SELECT * 
FROM `a:b.c.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX between '20180601' and '20180630' # JUNE
# and more ...
```

Comment: I've added an image of the limitation. 100 tables max.