# Preview all tables in MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database which is poorly documented and I am attempting to understand what is in each of the 50 tables located in the database. I want to just see the first few rows to get an idea of this.

For a single table I could type `SELECT * FROM TABLENAME1 LIMIT 10` and it works, but I am loathe to type this 50 times. Is there a way from the command line I can get output for all tables? Could I store this output somewhere?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26496864/how-to-loop-through-all-sql-tables) which uses the `sp_MSforeachtable` command to accomplish this (`sp_MSforeachtable @command1="select count(*) from ?";`) but that gave me the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sp_MSforeachtable @command1="select count(*) from ?"' at line 1

(I'm using MySQL 5.5 on an Ubuntu 18.04 server).

Comment: The question you linked to is for SQL-server, not MySQL.

Comment: There's nothing built-in that does this. You can write a stored procedure that loops over the table names in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a little sh script like this:

```
mysql -uroot -pYOURPW -Dbernd -N -e'SHOW TABLES' |
while read t
do
 echo;
 echo $t;
 echo;
 mysql -uroot pYOURPW -Dbernd  -e"SELECT * FROM $t LIMIT 10";
done
```