# Retrieving n row from SQL query

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I want to retrive only a row from a N row result of a SQL query. For example:

```
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT ..... ")
strResult = rs.Fields(0)
```

Query result:

```
30
45
70
....
```

How can i use the second value (20) from this query for example? Either by VBA or altering the sql query.
I'm using SQL server. There are the "LIMIT" or "TOP" commands but they are for a different purpose.

Comment: The second value is 45, by the way.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16777/2321042

Answer (score 0):

This may helps you
OFFSET n ROWS means after n rows
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY means getting one row
but it requires ORDER BY statement

```
SELECT * from table
ORDER BY <columns>
OFFSET n ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me... I am using SQL SERVER 2005

Comment: Maybe from the side of vba is more feasible... Instead of rs.Fields(0) how can I retrive all elements of a query so I can use them as I want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() function. You will have to select ROW_NUMBER over some ordered column and then you can query your selection using WHERE cla

```
USE AdventureWorks2012; 
GO
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SalesYTD DESC) AS Row, 
    FirstName, LastName, ROUND(SalesYTD,2,1) AS "Sales YTD" 
FROM Sales.vSalesPerson
WHERE TerritoryName IS NOT NULL AND SalesYTD <> 0;
```

Use common table expression to query your ROW Number

```
WITH OrderedEmployees(Row, FirstName, LastName)
As(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY FirstName DESC) AS Row, 
        FirstName, LastName
    FROM Employees
) 
SELECT * FROM 
OrderedEmployees
WHERE Row = 2
```

You can check out this [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad546/1) and validate your query against it.

[Using Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)

[ROW_NUMBER (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx)

Comment: ROW_NUMBER returns the sequential number of a row, I want the row value

Comment: Then you can use common table expression along with Row_Number(). Let me edit my answer

Comment: It does'n work for me... "Invalid column name 'Row' "

Comment: can you paste your query over here ?

Comment: I have added sql fiddel link in my answer.