# Extract only the topline of data from a specific table SQL

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble extracting the topline of data from a table and joining it with other extracted fields from other tables.

I have 3 tables:

```
Person
Folder
Earnings
```

Person:

```
PERSONID |FORENAMES|SURNAME|DOB      |GENDER|NINO

1000000  |JOHNSTON |ALI    |10/10/80 |M     |JK548754A
```

Folder:

```
FOLDERID|FOLDERREF

1000000 |104567LK
```

Earnings:

```
FOLDERID|DATESTARTED|DATEENDED  |GROSSEARNINGS 

1000000 |01-04-2014 |31-03-2015 |31846.00      
1000000 |01-04-2013 |31-03-2014 |31160.04

1000000 |01-04-2012 |31-03-2013 |30011.04

1000000 |01-04-2011 |31-03-2012 |29123.94
```

I need my data to look like:

```
JOHNSTON |ALI| 10-10-1980 | 31-03-2015 | 31846.00 | 31649.60
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT A.PERSONID, A.SURNAME, A.FORENAMES, A.DOB, B.FOLDERREF, C.DATEENDED, C.GROSSEARNINGS, C.BASICEARNINGS, C.FLUCTUATINGEARNINGS

FROM PERSON A, FOLDER B, EARNINGS C

WHERE A.PERSONID = B.FOLDERID AND B.FOLDERID = C.FOLDERID
```

Which extracts all of the data from the EARNINGS table, but I only wish to extract the top line.

Any advice is greatly received.

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server?  They have different syntax for limiting the number of records returned.  You will also want to use an `ORDER BY` clause to define the sort order of the records.  Otherwise "the top line" doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select the nth row in a SQL database table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568/how-to-select-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-database-table)

Comment: What is the final field in your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just the data from the latest date then you could do something like the query below. Bear in mind, you're using fields like c.BasicEarnings and c.FluctuatingEarnings that you don't have in table 'Earnings'

```
SELECT a.PersonID
    ,a.Suranme
    ,a.Forenames
    ,a.DOB
    ,b.FolderRef
    ,c.DateEnded
    ,c.GrossEarnings
FROM Person a
JOIN Folder b ON a.FolderID = b.FolderID
JOIN (
    SELECT e.FolderID
        ,e.DateEnded
        ,e.GrossEarnings
    FROM Earnings e
    JOIN (
        SELECT FolderID
            ,MAX(DateEnded) DateEnded
        FROM Earnings
        GROUP BY FolderID
        ) m ON e.FolderID = m.FolderID
        AND e.DateEnded = m.DateEnded
    ) c ON a.FolderID = c.FolderID
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the final field in your expected output is `GROSSEARNINGS` and by *"I only wish to extract the top line"* you mean latest (by date) then use `GROUP BY` with a `MAX` function.

```
SELECT p.FORENAMES, p.SURNAME, p.DOB, MAX(e.DATEENDED), e.GROSSEARNINGS, e.BASICEARNINGS
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN Earnings e ON p.PERSONID = e.FOLDERID
GROUP BY p.FORENAMES, p.SURNAME, p.DOB, e.GROSSEARNINGS, e.BASICEARNINGS
```