# Getting the next record MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a query where I could get the next record from this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEmBW.png)? (for example I will query to get the 'For Assignment' but instead I want the 'Assigned' to be the output.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select * from table_name where stepID = (select min(stepID) from table_name where stepID > 1)
```

Comment: Thank you but I already fixed it. I'll just mark this as the answer later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **limit** and **offset** to select the row.

Refer this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/16606/1294870

Answer (score 0):

You can get next record using this:

```
- SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE stepID > 2 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

Hope this will help you!