# Finding the rank of a value in a most common list

Tags: sql, count, sql-order-by, where-clause, rank

I got a database table containing some names and some numbers looks like following:

```
first last    number
max   muster  1
max   juster  2
max   huster  3
jen   muster  4
jen   jenker  5
ian   hoster  6
...
```

I query the most common first name by:

```
SELECT first, COUNT(*) AS value FROM table
GROUP BY first
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

I would like to know the ranking of first name 'ian' of this database table. In this case it is the 3rd common first name and above query gives me following:

```
    first value
1   max   3
2   jen   2
3   ian   1
```

**What I would like is a code for following:**

```
    first value
3   ian   1
```

**or something similar so that I can reach the number "3" with giving the `first='ian'` because it is the 3rd common name in my table. How should I query it?**

EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT first, COUNT(*) AS value FROM table
GROUP BY first
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

# So far we ordered the list from most common to least common

FILTER WHERE first='ian'

# We filtered the other names so that only first='ian' stays in the query,
# and we did not lose the index value (in this case 3) of the 'ian'
```

ofc this won't work, however I think you understand what I am searching for.

Comment: This look like a duplicate of :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568/how-to-select-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-database-table

Comment: I don't select/search the row like the question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568/how-to-select-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-database-table I search for a name and want to learn the row of the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select first_name, count(*) as cnt, rank() over(order by count(*) desc) as rn
    from mytable
    group by first_name
) t
where first_name = 'ian'
```

This gives you the the rank of "Ian".

Comment: above code with where first='ian' generates a table with only ian and ian rank would be 1 because it is the only entry in this table

Comment: @oakca: the query does what you ask for. The subquery ranks all records, *then* the outer query filters on the target `name`. Please try the query.

Comment: You are right. I am sorry, I did not copy pasted the code you wrote, and therefore somehow I had a wrong output. I got some questions though please answer them in your answer (so you edit and I will be able to upvote). 1) what is this 't'? what does it do in your code? 2) the rank appears to be having a column name of 'm'. Why is that? where do you define it? @GMB

Comment: @oakca: `t` is an alias for the subquery. There is no `m` in the query, though.

Comment: >There is no `m` in the query, though. >> But somehow my ranking column's name appears to be `m`. And I don't know why pgAdmin4 decides to give this name. @GMB

Comment: @oakca: that’s `rn`, which is the alias given to the rank in the subquery. You can change that to whatever you prefer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:
(works with PostgreSQL)

```
SELECT * from
(
  select ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY value desc) AS rownumber, firstname, value
  from
  (
    SELECT firstname, COUNT(*) AS value
    FROM public.people as pp
    GROUP BY firstname
  ) as goo
) AS foo
WHERE foo.firstname like 'ian%';
```

This gives the expected result:

```
3   ian                     1
```

or if you wants to get the 3rd result:

```
SELECT * from
(
  select ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY value desc) AS rownumber, firstname, value
  from
  (
    SELECT firstname, COUNT(*) AS value
    FROM public.people as pp
    GROUP BY firstname
  ) as goo
) AS foo
WHERE rownumber = 3
```

or if you want to LIMIT the intermediate result like this:

```
SELECT * from
(
  select ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY value desc) AS rownumber, firstname, value
  from
  (
    SELECT firstname, COUNT(*) AS value
    FROM public.people as pp
    GROUP BY firstname
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) desc
    limit 3
  ) as goo
) AS foo
WHERE rownumber = 3
```

This gives the expected result:

```
3   ian                     1
```