# how to select the n'th last element in database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

How do I select the nth **last** row from a table in sqlite3 database (Python)?

(with an Id Column in ascending order)

Comment: I forgot to mention that it can only be the nth last row and nothing else

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select the nth row in a SQL database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568/how-to-select-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-database-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as the nth last row in a table.  In SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

If you have a column that specifies the ordering, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
order by <ordering column> desc
limit 1 offset n - 1;
```

In SQLite, tables are often created with `rowid` as a column that is often used to represent the insert order (although that might not always be true).  That may be what you want to use as the ordering column.

Comment: There are a number of cases where rowid will not indicate insertion order.

Comment: @Shawn. . . I changed the verbiage on that.