# How to select a random row from a SQL database table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am attempting to retrieve a random row in my table from Visual Studio's database.
However, it is unable to retrieve a random row and throws this specific exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.'

This is my function code to retrieve a random table row:

```
Voucher randomVoucher = null;
int voucherID;
string voucherName, voucherDescription, discountCode;
decimal discountAmount;

string queryStr = "SELECT * FROM Voucher ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1; ";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connStr);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryStr, conn);

conn.Open();
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dr.Read())
{
    voucherID = int.Parse(dr["VoucherID"].ToString());
    voucherName = dr["VoucherName"].ToString();
    voucherDescription = dr["VoucherDescription"].ToString();
    discountAmount = decimal.Parse(dr["DiscountAmount"].ToString());
    discountCode = dr["DiscountCode"].ToString();

    randomVoucher = new Voucher(voucherID, voucherName, voucherDescription, discountAmount, discountCode);
}
else
{
    randomVoucher = null;
}

conn.Close();
dr.Close();
dr.Dispose();

return randomVoucher;
```

Comment: What is _"Visual Studio's database"_? Do you mean SQL Server Express?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't use `LIMIT`, it uses `SELECT TOP 1 ...` instead, different syntax.

Comment: Is `RAND()` really a valid argument for `ORDER BY`? I would considering just doing it in two queries, a count, creating a random number in c# and then [getting that specific row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568/how-to-select-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-database-table).

Comment: TOP 1 only returns the first row everytime.

Comment: change the query to `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Voucher ORDER BY NEWID()`

Comment: Apart from the error in using LIMIT instead of TOP (this is what the duplicates tells you) the correct way to get a random order in sql server is ORDER BY NEWID()

Comment: Thanks! Using both TOP 1 and Order By NEWID() works.

Answer (score 0):

`Limit` is a `Mysql` statement and one equivalent for it in `Sql Server` can be using `OFFSET` and `FETCH`

```
string queryStr = "SELECT* FROM Voucher ORDER BY newid()  OFFSET 10 rows FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;";
```

It reads 10 rows of a randomly sorted database starting from the 10th row.

Comment: Read the docs: _Returns a pseudo-random float value from 0 through 1, exclusive._

Answer (score 0):

You can get random number from range of 1 to your table records count then select that one from table and get the result!

pseudo code:

```
// This is like a entity framework sample,
// You can get it from query by using SQL COUNT => SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $TABLE_NAME$;
tableRecordCount = table.Count();
//generating random number more then 0 and less then tableRecordCount
int randomNum = random.Next(1, tableRecordCount); 
//Then getting row with this id;
//Or with query => SELECT * FROM $TABLE_NAME$ WHERE id = randomNum ...
var randomRow = table.firstOrDefault(r => r.id == randomNum);
```

So if "id" is your "Primary key" column and the values are unique you will get one record with id that is our generated random number! Good luck!

Comment: While this could work, it requires two queries against the database or downloading the entire table in memory

Comment: This seems like it will work, just needs to check if the random ID actually exists in the database and has not been delete, if not pick a random ID again.